# Dynamic Creation of Div inside an array and Appending data to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching result from database and i want too append it to dynamically created div.

```
for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
    {
        selected = $(".content" + (j + 1));
        ajax1(arr[j]);
    }
    function ajax1(pref) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "../handlers/guestpreference.ashx",
            data: { "pref": pref },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: guestsuccess,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
function guestsuccess(resultset)
    {       
       $.each(resultset, function (i, data) {
            $(selected).append('<div class="blogpost" >');
            $(".blogpost").append("<div class='blogposth'>");
            $(".blogpost").append("<div class='blogpostf'>");
            $(".blogposth").append('<font style="font-size:30px; color:blue;padding-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">' + data.Name + '</font>');
            $(".blogpostf").append('<font style="font-size:30px; text-align:centre;">' + data.Title + '</font><br>');
            $(".blogpostf").append('<font style="text-align:left;float:left;">' + data.Post + '</font><br>');
            $(".blogpostf").append('<hr>');
            var likes = data.Likes;
            if (likes > 0)
                $(".blogpostf").append('<font style="font-size:10px;text-align:left;float:left;">' + likes + ' &nbsp;people like it.</font><br>');
            else
                $(".blogpostf").append('<font style="font-size:10px;text-align:left;float:left;">Nobody like it.</font><br>');
            $(selected).append("<br>");

       });

    }
```

Here `selected` holds the class where i have to append `.blogpost`.
this code is working fine if i have only 1 row of result but in case of multiple result the results are being appended to previously created div.
Since i have CSS for `.blogpost` `.blogposth` `.blogpostf` how can i modify my code so that i can append value uniquely.

Comment: Provide a fiddle  if possible..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mmpuov74/5/
ideally, what is want is that it create three seperate divs but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create object of div which you append to  "selected" . check demo on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/mmpuov74/6/)

```
   $blogpost = $('<div class="blogpost" ></div>'); 
   $blogpost.appendTo('#app');
   $blogposth = $("<div class='blogposth'><div>");
   $blogpost.append($blogposth);
   $blogpostf = $("<div class='blogpostf'><div>");
   $blogpost.append($blogpostf);


   $blogposth.append('<font style="font-size:30px; color:blue;padding-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">Name</font>');
   $blogpostf.append('<font style="font-size:30px; text-align:centre;">Title</font><br>');
   $blogpostf.append('<font style="text-align:left;float:left;">POST</font><br>');
   $blogpostf.append('<hr>');
```

Comment: You have Written the code twice, what if i have to append it n number of times by for loop.

Comment: Yeah I checked.. Its Working fine in the fiddle, but i dont know why even after using same codes in my system the values are being appended to previously created divs..
This is exactly what i want to do http://jsfiddle.net/mmpuov74/7/ but its not working..

Comment: M out for lunch .. Back in 30 min. Can you update fiddle you tried with my code